# DropDownListFor em um for

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou tentando preencher com o valor selecionada um `DropDownList` dentro de um `for`, porém não esta funcionando adequadamente.
O que ocorre é que quando a `Action Index`  retorna o model para a `View`, os valores não estão vindo selecionados, ficando sempre o primeiro item do `DropDownList` selecionado.

Montei um pequeno exemplo para facilitar.

> **Editei** adicionando as sugestões do @RichardDias
>
> Para ajudar, fiz um commit no GitHub https://github.com/pablotdv/TesteDropDownEnum

Classes

```
public class Principal
{
    public MeuEnum Item { get; set; }
    public List<Teste> Teste { get; set; }
}

    public class Teste
    {
        public MeuEnum item { get; set; }
    }

    public enum MeuEnum
    {
        Item0 = 0,

        Item1 = 1,

        Item2 = 2,

        Item3 = 3,

        Item4 = 4,

        Item5 = 5,

        Item6 = 6,

        Item7 = 7,

        Item8 = 8,
    }

    public static class Helpers
    {
        public static SelectList MeuEnumItens(this HtmlHelper html)
        {
            var item0 = new SelectListItem() { Value = "Item0", Text = "0" };
            var item1 = new SelectListItem() { Value = "Item1", Text = "1" };
            var item2 = new SelectListItem() { Value = "Item2", Text = "2" };
            var item3 = new SelectListItem() { Value = "Item3", Text = "3" };
            var item4 = new SelectListItem() { Value = "Item4", Text = "4" };
            var item5 = new SelectListItem() { Value = "Item5", Text = "5" };
            var item6 = new SelectListItem() { Value = "Item6", Text = "6" };
            var item7 = new SelectListItem() { Value = "Item7", Text = "7" };
            var item8 = new SelectListItem() { Value = "Item8", Text = "8" };

            return new SelectList(new[] { item0, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8 }, "Value", "Text");
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Principal p = new Principal()
        {
            Item = MeuEnum.Item6
        };
        p.Teste = new List<Teste>();

        p.Teste.Add(new Teste() { item = MeuEnum.Item0 });
        p.Teste.Add(new Teste() { item = MeuEnum.Item1 });
        p.Teste.Add(new Teste() { item = MeuEnum.Item2 });
        p.Teste.Add(new Teste() { item = MeuEnum.Item3 });

        return View(p);
    }
}
```

View

```
    @model TesteDropDownEnum.Controllers.Principal
@using TesteDropDownEnum.Controllers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<!--Assim funciona-->
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Item, Html.MeuEnumItens(), "Selecione", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Teste.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Origem da Mercadoria @Model.Teste[i].item</label>
                <!--Assim não funciona-->
                @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Teste[i].item, Html.MeuEnumItens(Model.Teste[i].item), "Selecione", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Na edição que você fez, no método `MeuEnumItens` você deve verificar se o item recebido é igual ao item do enum.

Comment: Modifiquei o método `MeuEnumItens` na minha resposta para dar um exemplo.

Comment: Já havia feito a mudança que tu fez, mas não resolveu também.

Comment: Realizei a modificação do tipo de retorno do método MeuEnumItens3 para um IEnumerable<SelectListItem> e retornei diretamente a lista e o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: A resposta foi editada. Tenta replicar a edição para o método MeuEnumItens3 e verá que vai funcionar. Aqui funcionou com o seu código do GIT.

Comment: Criei um fork no Git, se quiser dá uma olhada lá.

Comment: @RichardDias vamos olhar sim.

Comment: Fiz um *pull request* com a resposta do @RichardDias + o BeginCollectionItem. Só realizar um *merge*.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez essa modificação é para que os nomes dos campos fiquem corretos? Teria a real necessidade de utilizar a partialview ou poderia fazer o `using(Html.BeginCollectionItem)` antes do for e fazer de boa o DropDown? Questiono pois nunca usei esse pacote e provavelmente em breve precisarei um um projeto, e quero aproveitar e fazer desse jeito se for poupar trabalho.

Comment: @RichardDias Dá pra fazer sem a *Partial*, mas fica mais difícil por causa dos campos com *expression*. O que você precisar é só me chamar no chat ou me chama no Facebook que te ajudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O objeto `SelectListItem` possui uma propriedade `Selected`. se ela estiver com o valor `true`, esse item é que virá selecionado. Caso nenhum item possua um valor `true` para essa propriedade o valor selecionado é o parâmetro `optionalLabel` do `DropDownListFor`, caso exista. No exemplo abaixo eu modifiquei e coloquei como "Selecione". Você fazendo isso o problema de sempre vir o primeiro selecionado deve acabar.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Teste[i].item, Html.MeuEnumItens(), "Selecione", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Seria interessante que o seu método `MeuEnumItens` aceitasse mais um parâmetro opcional (`MeuEnum? valorSelecionado`) e realizasse a comparação para setar o valor da propriedade `Selected` do objeto 'SelectListItem'. Aproveitei e deixei uma dica de como modificar a criação de selectlists de enumeradores.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MeuEnumItens(this HtmlHelper html, MeuEnum? itemSelecionado)
{
    var lista = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (MeuEnum item in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(MeuEnum)))
    {
        lista.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.ToString("F"), Value = item.ToString(), Selected = (itemSelecionado.HasValue ? itemSelecionado.Value == item : false) });
    }

    return lista;
}
```

Por fim, faça uso do [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) para gerar a lista de *DropDowns* dinamicamente, com o *binding* correto:

### `Index.cshtml`

```
foreach (var teste in Model.Testes)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Item", teste)
}
```

### `_Item.cshtml`

```
@model TesteDropDownEnum.Controllers.Teste
@using TesteDropDownEnum.Controllers

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Testes"))
{
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Origem da Mercadoria @Model.item</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.item, Html.MeuEnumItens(Model.item), "Selecione", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: O engraçado que fora do `for` funciona normal, sem precisar de parâmetro adicional.

Comment: Tente usar um `foreach` ao invés do `for`. Utilizar um editor pode ser uma outra saída.

Comment: Mas é que com um `foreach` não consigo dar `post` e com o `for` sim.

Comment: Esta resposta está correta, mas precisa citar o [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) para estar completa. O problema central não é a geração do elemento de `form`, mas o *binding* como um todo.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez teria como fazer um exemplo?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o BeginCollectionItem é um package separado. O Binding automático não é obrigatório para ficar correto. Se o método de extensão dele receber um parâmetro a mais conforme dito na resposta ele poderá validar se o item do enum do `foreach` é o valor passado por parâmetro e setar a propriedade `Selected = true;` que irá funcionar normalmente.

Comment: Sim, eu concordo, mas ele quer um pouco mais.

Comment: @PabloVargas Vou fazer um *fork* do seu pacote e coloco tudo lá.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Blz, agradeço a colaboração

Comment: O mais estranho que eu adicionei um `@Html.DropDownList("Teste", Html.MeuEnumItens(MeuEnum.Item5))` e não renderizou a `View` com o `Item5` selecionado.